# segmentation fault on method call

Tags: methods, segmentation-fault, call

i am getting a segmentation fault while trying to call the `addEdge(int, int)` method. the `calling code` is below. Can anyone help?

```
    void addEdge(int i, int j) 
{
        if (i >= 0 && j > 0) 
    {
        Node* whereto;
        whereto = linkedAdjacencyList[i];
        if(whereto != NULL) //the segmentation fault occurs here
        {
            while(whereto->adj != NULL)
            {whereto = whereto->adj;}
            whereto->adj = linkedAdjacencyList[j];
        }
        else{linkedAdjacencyList[i]->adj = linkedAdjacencyList[j];}
        whereto = linkedAdjacencyList[j];
        if(whereto != NULL)
        {
            while(whereto->adj != NULL)
            {whereto = whereto->adj;}
            whereto->adj = linkedAdjacencyList[i];
        }
        else{linkedAdjacencyList[j]->adj = linkedAdjacencyList[i];}
            }
    }


std::istream& operator>>(std::istream& in, UndirectedGraph& g)
{
    int numVerticies;
    in >> numVerticies;

    g = UndirectedGraph(numVerticies);
int edges;
in >> edges;
g.edges = edges;
for(int i = 0; i < edges; i++)
{
    int first;
    int second;
    in >> first >> second;
    g.addEdge(first, second);
}
```

any ideas?

Comment: `addEdge` passes `first` and `second` as the parameters. What if I send 100, 200 ? Is the program still valid or prone to segmentation faults ?

Comment: @Mahesh yes, tried it with hardcoded integers and still got the segmentation fault in the same place :/

Comment: @JocobL - I just gave those numbers as an example. Since, you are operating on `i,j` in the method, you should check at those places whether `->` leads to valid memory locations.

Comment: forgot to get past some input values. the segmentation fault now occurs at `if(whereto != NULL)`, the first instance. i have put a comment in the code to show the exact location

Comment: So, `linkedAdjacencyList[i];` is not giving a valid memory location for the value of `i` you are passing.

Comment: and yes, @Mahesh, i just `cout`'d the variables `first` and `second` and they hold int values of `1` and `2` respectively

Comment: @Mahesh , very quickly, how would i declare the node pointers, instead of

   `Node* linkedAdjacencyList[i];
   Node* p = new Node(i);
   linkedAdjacencyList[i] = p;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would say that your 'g' object was not instantiated properly. Create it using 'new' and use -> operator to call addEdge function.

Comment: i updated the posted code to include more background. when i tried to do `new` and `->` i got compilation errors..